# Videogame like object variant switcher

Tags: add-on

Is there an addon for Blender that allows a person to switch out parts on a model car like you can in a videogame? (One click selection that shows one part variant and hides the previous, and also lines up the parts so when they switch, it doesn't look off kilter)

Comment: Have you thought about using group instances on parent empties?

Comment: Just watched a part of a youtube video on them, I'm not wanting to copy objects multiple times (in this case). I'm trying to have two objects share all the same information except for material and topology, if that makes sense.(I don't know if group instancing allows for that because I've never to my knowledge used them)

Comment: You can switch witch group they reference aka switch the part

Answer (score 3):

If you have different parts/part groups that you would like to switch out, then group those parts, and reference them from empty objects:

[image]

This forms a good basis for using drivers in the future to automate the switching by mixing drivers with the use of Custom Properties:

[image]