# how to make blender render less from far objects?

Tags: modeling, rendering, cycles-render-engine, camera, video

(i use blender 2.79)
in video games, the farther is the object the fewer details it has, and that of course to save memory
but how to do it in blender 
if you have 2 complex objects and one of them is closer to the camera than the other 
how to make the farther object get less render?

Comment: Dude, breathe! Try to use punctuation, structures like paragraphs and so on. Some images would also help. Try to describe your problem as detailed as possible. It's really hard to get anything out of your question, when it sounds like incoherent ramblings.

Comment: **LOD** (Level of Detail). You may find this earlier post usefull:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64614/is-it-possible-to-have-automatic-lod-level-of-detail-on-large-scenes. I